# How to split count() query into 10 groups in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, rownum

I am currently using mysql and I have to split the data into 10 groups.

For example, if the total count of data is 90, it should go like

```
 1~9,
10~18,
19~27,
28~36,
37~45,
46~54,
55~63, 
64~72,
73~81, 
82~90.
```

if the total count of data is 100, it should go like

```
 1~10,
11~20,
21~30,
31~40,
41~50,
51~60,
61~70, 
71~80,
81~90, 
91~100.
```

Can anyone give me a clue to split the data into 10 groups. I used rownum, but it did not work....

```
select total.row_num,
                total.name,
                total.reg,
                total.id,
                total.motspd
        from(
            select
                (@row_num:=@row_num+1) AS row_num,
                cg.group_name as name,
                td.reg_date as reg,
                td.car_id as id,
                td.mcu_motspd as motspd
            from
                cartracker.tracker_data td
            left join car c on (c.car_device_no = td.car_id)
            left join car_group cg on (c.car_group_no = cg.car_group_no)
            where cg.car_group_no = "1"
            group by DATE_FORMAT(td.reg_date, "%Y%M%d%h%m")
            )total
```

This is a result of a query, but it shows wrong row numbers.I want row_num goes from 0 to the end number of the data. but, in the picture, it starts from 44,713. can anyone help me to fix row num as it starts from 0 to the end number of the data.
[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5FO3.png)

Comment: Why don't you do this in your application layer? It would be so much easier!

Comment: split how?  please show your table structure, sample data, and expected results

Comment: [NTILE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile)

Comment: *I want row_num goes from 0 to the end number of the data. but, in the picture, it starts from 44,713 and mixed up* Variables processing order is not correct while GROUP BY is used. Perform grouping in subquery, then process using variable in outer query with definite ORDER BY.

Comment: I still don't understand, what the result is supposed to look like. Do you want to select and show all tracker_data rows, each with a number from 1 to 10 indicating to which block the row belongs? And if so, by what order? Please show a little example with 12 tracker_data rows for instance. Show us the result you expect.

Comment: What is your MySQL version? As you are fumbling with variables, I suppose you are not on MySQL 8, yet?

Comment: Your query seems to have nothing to do with the question in your title.

Answer (score 0):

I am going by the question in the title:

> I am currently using mysql and I have to split the data into 10 groups.

That is exactly what the function [`ntile()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) does.  So:

```
select t.*,
       ntile(10) over (order by <whatever>) as tile
from t;
```

I have no idea what the query has to do with this question.

Answer (score -2):

Haven't realize OP want with dynamic table BEFORE re-edit, this is not cleaver and require a lot of time to process though. switch `a` with OP table name and create rownumber first.

```
DECLARE @TotalNum INT;
DECLARE @Num INT;
DECLARE @NUm2 INT;
DECLARE @COUNTS INT;

SET @COUNTS = (select count(rownum) from a)/10
SET @TotalNum = 10 
SET @Num =1
SET @Num2 =0     

WHILE @Num <= @TotalNum  
BEGIN    

  update a 
  set a.flag = @Num
  where a.rownum >= (@COUNTS)*@NUM2+1 and a.rownum <= @NUM*(@COUNTS)
      
    SET @Num = @NUM + 1
    SET @Num2 = @NUM2 + 1
END
```

Comment: How do you plan to make this work with dynamic number of records?